# how to get the mail sender profile image in inbox mail using mailcore2

Tags: ios, iphone, mailcore2

I am doing iPhone mobile app using mailcore2. In this application i need to fetch the mail sender profile image or sender user image when i get the inbox messages. I am using following code.

```
MCOIMAPSession *session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
[session setHostname:@"imap.gmail.com"];
[session setPort:993];
[session setUsername:@"ADDRESS@gmail.com"];
[session setPassword:@"123456"];
[session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeTLS];

MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders;
NSString *folder = @"INBOX";
MCOIndexSet *uids = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)];

MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOperation = [session fetchMessagesByUIDOperationWithFolder:folder requestKind:requestKind uids:uids];

[fetchOperation start:^(NSError * error, NSArray * fetchedMessages, MCOIndexSet * vanishedMessages) {
    //We've finished downloading the messages!

    //Let's check if there was an error:
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error downloading message headers:%@", error);
    }

    //And, let's print out the messages...
    NSLog(@"The post man delivereth:%@", fetchedMessages);
}];
```

[image]

Any of you share the solution for this. How to get the sender profile image using MailCore2  MCOIMAPSession or any other solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: MailCore 2 doesn't help you with profile pictures. Gravatar helps a little bit though.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Then how to get mailer profile pictures can your share your comments.

Comment: how to get mailer profile or any other way to fetch that details.

Comment: @iSara Mailcore doesn't get contact pictures. As Hoà said take a look at Gravatar (http://en.gravatar.com) or try pulling contact pictures from the local address book using the iOS Address Book API.